# Show that the histogram estimator is an unbiased estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

So the question is asking to show that the histogram estimator $\mathbb{E}_p[\hat{p}_n(x)]$  is unbiased. So I worked and found that the histogram estimator is $$\hat{p}_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(\frac{\hat{p}_j}{h}indicator(x\in B_j))$$ Where m is the number of chosen bins for the histogram and $B_j$ is like this: $$mbins: B_1 = [0,\frac{1}{m}), B_2 = [\frac{1}{m},\frac{2}{m}),.....B_m=[\frac{m-1}{m},1]$$
Furthermore, the bandwidth $h = \frac{1}{m}$, $\hat{p}_j=\frac{Y}{n}$ with $Y_j=$ the number of observations in $B_j$....... Now I understand that I am supposed to integrate the histogram estimator that I obtained since it is a continuous random variable. But I do not understand where to begin or even what the bounds are. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode.

Comment: I just wanted to use an indicator function but couldn't find any... so I just wrote indicator

Comment: A conventional notation for the indicator function of a set $S$ is $\mathbb1_S$. Anyway, my comment wasn't related to the content; it applies quite generally to text in math mode.

Comment: By 'histogram estimator' do you mean [empirical distribution function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)?

Comment: basically, I am to find whether $\hat{p}_n$ is an unbiased estimator. the histogram estimator is $\hat{p}_n$

Comment: You have a discrete distribution. It's expectation is found by summing a series, not by integration.